# Unable to loop values in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a scenario where I want to read file using python.

**Data in file: ABC.txt**

```
"A","B","C"
"E","F","A"
"S","H","DD","ADF"
"G","L","LI","LO","YAU"
"H","KK","AD"
"J","GH","KL"
"L","OP","AM"
"O","LA","WE"
```

**My Code:**

```
with open('ABC.txt',"r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    parameter = {"empid": "3", "empcd": "56", "ide": [lines]}
```

What I am actually looking is read file line by line and
should be passed as an argument to `"ide": [line]`.

Assume it goes through first iteration, entire string `-> "A","B","C"` will be passed to "`ide": ["A", "B", "C"]`.

```
parameter = {"empid": "3", "empcd": "56", "ide": ["A", "B", "C"]}
```

**second iteration:**

```
parameter = {"empid": "3", "empcd": "56", "ide": ["E", "F", "A"]}
```

**third iteration:**

```
parameter = {"empid": "3", "empcd": "56", "ide": ["S", "H", "DD", "ADF"]}
```

Loop will continue until all records are read from file.

In Unix I know how to read file but not good with python how to achieve this using python ?

**My Unix code:**

```sh
while read -r line 
do 
    var=`echo $line` 
    parameter = '{"empid": "3", "empcd": "56", "ide": [ $(( var )) ] }'
done < ABC.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert lines to list. For example:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

with open("ABC.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        print(
            {"empid": "3", "empcd": "56", "ide": literal_eval("[" + line + "]")}
        )
```

Prints:

```py
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['E', 'F', 'A']}
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['S', 'H', 'DD', 'ADF']}
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['G', 'L', 'LI', 'LO', 'YAU']}
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['H', 'KK', 'AD']}
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['J', 'GH', 'KL']}
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['L', 'OP', 'AM']}
{'empid': '3', 'empcd': '56', 'ide': ['O', 'LA', 'WE']}
```

Comment: I don't want to print want to get into parameter line in place of "ide" : [ values]

Comment: @codeholic24 So instead of `print()` do `parameter = {"empid": "3", "empcd": "56", "ide": literal_eval("[" + line + "]")}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json`:

```
import json

for line in open("ABC.txt"):
     parameter = { "empid":"3", "empcd":"56", "ide": json.loads(f"[{line}]") }
     print(parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a lambda function

```
fun1 = lambda x:x.strip().replace('"','').split(",")
new_lines = [fun1(i) for i in lines]
print(new_lines)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'A'], ['S', 'H', 'DD', 'ADF'], ['G', 'L', 'LI', 'LO', 'YAU']]
```